# zipfile throws IO exception

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to create an object of type zipfile; but it seems that in certain situations this object creation is causing a IO exception to be thrown. The file permissions are :

```
-rw-r----- 1 rhp gi 4752434 Aug 16 10:33 /tmp/abc.jar
```

The permissions when the issue does not occur look like this:

```
-rw-r----- 1 bp db 4927518 Aug 16 10:18 /tmp/abc.jar
```

While looking at the zipfile source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/zip/ZipFile.java#ZipFile.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%2Cint%29) I am not entirely sure what could be causing the IO exception to happen. Whether it is the file.lastModified() or the actual jni call or the users having different permissions

Comment: If the user doesn't have permission to delete the file, that's what'll happen.

Comment: Is the file getting created even after the exception?

Comment: @DaveNewton the user has permission to perform the necessary operation.

Comment: @JamesJithin no the zipfile object does not get created if there is a exception. But I would like to understand how and why the ZipFile constructor is throwing the exception

Comment: @bhavs, is it because another file exists with the same name?

Comment: @JamesJithin no we don't have another file with the same name.